# How to tell whether an object is a nested cell array

Tags: matlab

How can I tell the difference between the following two objects:

```
cellArray = {'Var1' 'Var2'};

nestedCellArray = {{'Var1' 'Var2'}};
```

This is important since `table(:, cellArray)` works but `table(:, nestedCellArray)` doesn't.

Comment: Your two examples look identical too me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to check that all of the elements of the outer cell array are of a particular class using [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
cellArray = {'Var1' 'Var2'};
nestedCellArray = {{'Var1' 'Var2'}};

A1 = all(cellfun(@ischar, cellArray))
A2 = all(cellfun(@ischar, nestedCellArray))
```

or you can use [`iscell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/iscell.html) to check that none of the elements of the outer cell array is a cell itself:

```
A1 = ~any(cellfun(@iscell, cellArray))
A2 = ~any(cellfun(@iscell, nestedCellArray))
```

If you know something about the elements of your cell array, you could also concatenate it and use `iscell` to test the result (it's possible that this is the fastest in many cases, but it may not work if the objects in your cell array don't concatenate together):

```
A1 = ~iscell([cellArray{:}])
A2 = ~iscell([nestedCellArray{:}])
```

Lastly, you could also use the [`'isclass'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html#zmw57dd0e104385_block) option (appears this may be deprecated as of R2015b) of `cellfun` in the same two ways as above:

```
A1 = all(cellfun('isclass', cellArray, 'char'))
A2 = all(cellfun('isclass', nestedCellArray, 'char'))
```

or

```
A1 = ~any(cellfun('isclass', cellArray, 'cell'))
A2 = ~any(cellfun('isclass', nestedCellArray, 'cell'))
```

None of the above `cellfun` options are efficient for very large numbers of elements in the outer cell array as `cellfun` looks at all elements and doesn't [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). In such a case, you could use a `for` loop. Here's a short function:

```
function tf = isNotNested(C)
tf = true;
for i = 1:numel(C)
    if iscell(C{i})
        tf = false;
        break;
    end
end
```